Prove $Max(L_1,L_2,L_3)\neq L_2$:$L_i=\frac{S_i^2}{n_i}+\frac{(S-S_i)^2}{n-n_i}$;$S=\sum S_i$;$n=\sum n_i$;$\frac{S_i}{n_i}>\frac{S_{i-1}}{n_{i-1}}$
I will state my question first, and after that, I will write how I arrived to it.
You do not really need to see how I arrived to the question, but I just thought it would be rude not to explain that.
My question:
I know that the following three expressions are true:
$$\frac{S_3}{n_3}>\frac{S_2}{n_2}>\frac{S_1}{n_1};$$
$$S=S_1+S_2+S_3;$$
$$n=n_1+n_2+n_3;$$
And we set:
$$L_1=\frac{S_1^2}{n_1}+\frac{(S-S_1)^2}{n-n_1};$$
$$L_2=\frac{S_2^2}{n_2}+\frac{(S-S_2)^2}{n-n_2};$$
$$L_3=\frac{S_3^2}{n_3}+\frac{(S-S_3)^2}{n-n_3};$$
And I would like to prove that
$$Max(L_1,L_2,L_3)\neq L_2 $$
How I arrived to it:
I have a sample of $n$ observations from a linear regression model with only 2 dummy variables.
$$Y_i=\beta_0+\beta_1D1_i+\beta_2D2_i+\epsilon_i=\mu_i+\epsilon_i$$
$D1_i$ is equal to $1$ if $i=n_1+1,...,n_1+n_2$ and $0$ otherwise.
$D2_i$ is equal to $1$ if $i=n_1+n_2+1,...,n$ and $0$ otherwise.
We define $b_0$, $b_1$, $b_2$ as the OLS estimators for $\beta_0$, $\beta_1$, $\beta_2$ respectively.
It can be proven that the following three are true:
$$ b_0 = \frac{1}{n_1}\sum_{i=1}^{n_1} y_i $$
$$ b_0 + b_1 = \frac{1}{n_2}\sum_{i=n_1+1}^{n_1+n_2} y_i $$
$$ b_0 + b_2 = \frac{1}{n_3}\sum_{i=n_1+n_2+1}^{n} y_i $$
Now I make the assumption that the true number of coefficients of my model is $2$ instead of $3$:
$$Y_i=\beta_0+\beta_1D_i+\epsilon_i=\mu_i+\epsilon_i$$
This means that the sample came from either of the three following models:

$D_i$ is equal to $1$ if $i=n_1+1,...,n$ and $0$ otherwise.
$D_i$ is equal to $1$ if $i=1,...,n_1,n_1+n_2+1,...,n$ and $0$ otherwise.
$D_i$ is equal to $1$ if $i=n_1+n_2+1,...,n$ and $0$ otherwise.

If the first bullet point is true, then
$$ b_0 = \frac{1}{n_1}\sum_{i=1}^{n_1} y_i $$
$$ b_0 + b_1 = \frac{1}{(n_2+n_3)}\sum_{i=n_1+1}^{n} y_i $$
If instead the second bullet point is true, then
$$ b_0 = \frac{1}{n_2}\sum_{i=n_1+1}^{n_1+n_2} y_i $$
$$ b_0 + b_1 = \frac{1}{(n_1+n_3)}(\sum_{i=1}^{n_1} y_i+\sum_{i=n_1+n_2+1}^{n} y_i) $$
And finally if the third bullet point is true then
$$ b_0 = \frac{1}{(n_1+n_2)}\sum_{i=1}^{n_1+n_2} y_i $$
$$ b_0 + b_1 = \frac{1}{n_3}\sum_{i=n_1+n_2+1}^{n} y_i $$
3 quick definitions before I finish:
$$S_1=\sum_{i=1}^{n_1} y_i $$
$$S_2=\sum_{i=n_1+1}^{n_1+n_2} y_i $$
$$S_3=\sum_{i=n_1+n_2+1}^{n} y_i $$
Now, based on the observed sample, I want to know which of the three is more likely.
Looking at the sample I see that:
$$\frac{S_3}{n_3}>\frac{S_2}{n_2}>\frac{S_1}{n_1};$$
In order to see which of the three models is more likely I need to see in which of the three cases the following Residual sum of squares (RSS) is lower:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} (y_i-\hat\mu_i)^2$$
After many (but trivial) calculations you get back to my original question.
So my guess is that if $\frac{S_3}{n_3}>\frac{S_2}{n_2}>\frac{S_1}{n_1}$ is true then I can always exclude that the RSS is minimum with the hypothesis made in the second bullet point.
